# Why is FFT different in Swift than in Python?

Tags: python, swift, signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to port some python numpy code to Swift using the Accelerate framework.

In python I write

```
import numpy as np
frames = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
fftArray = np.fft.fft(frames, len(frames))
print(fftArray)
```

And the output is:

```
[10.+0.j -2.+2.j -2.+0.j -2.-2.j]
```

So in Swift I'm trying to calculate the FFT like this:

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

    func fftAnalyzer(frameOfSamples: [Float]) {
        // As above, frameOfSamples = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]            

        let analysisBuffer = frameOfSamples
        let frameCount = frameOfSamples.count

        var reals = [Float]()
        var imags = [Float]()
        for (idx, element) in analysisBuffer.enumerated() {
            if idx % 2 == 0 {
                reals.append(element)
            } else {
                imags.append(element)
            }
        }
        var complexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(realp: UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: reals), imagp: UnsafeMutablePointer(mutating: imags))

        let log2Size = Int(log2f(Float(frameCount)))

        guard let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(vDSP_Length(log2Size), Int32(kFFTRadix2)) else {
            return []
        }

        // Perform a forward FFT
        vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &(complexBuffer), 1, UInt(log2Size), Int32(FFT_FORWARD))

        let realFloats = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: complexBuffer.realp, count: Int(frameCount)))
        let imaginaryFloats = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: complexBuffer.imagp, count: Int(frameCount)))

        print(realFloats)
        print(imaginaryFloats)

        // Release the setup
        vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)

        return realFloats
    }
```

The realFloats and imaginaryFloats are printed like so:

```
[20.0, -4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-4.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Any ideas on what I should be doing differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not good at numpy, but according to [the doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft), `fft` takes complex-input. Then its equivalent would be `vDSP_fft_zip`, not `vDSP_fft_zrip`.

And your code causes buffer overflow or might cause dangling pointer, with all such things fixed I get this:

```
func fftAnalyzer(frameOfSamples: [Float]) -> [Float] {
    // As above, frameOfSamples = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

    let frameCount = frameOfSamples.count

    let reals = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: frameCount)
    defer {reals.deallocate()}
    let imags =  UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: frameCount)
    defer {imags.deallocate()}
    _ = reals.initialize(from: frameOfSamples)
    imags.initialize(repeating: 0.0)
    var complexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(realp: reals.baseAddress!, imagp: imags.baseAddress!)

    let log2Size = Int(log2(Float(frameCount)))
    print(log2Size)

    guard let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(vDSP_Length(log2Size), FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2)) else {
        return []
    }
    defer {vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)}

    // Perform a forward FFT
    vDSP_fft_zip(fftSetup, &complexBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(log2Size), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

    let realFloats = Array(reals)
    let imaginaryFloats = Array(imags)

    print(realFloats)
    print(imaginaryFloats)

    return realFloats
}
```

Printed

> ```
> [10.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0]
> [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0]
> ```

Comment: That works! Is the vDSP_fft_zrip the equivalent of fft.rfft?

Comment: Not exactly. We expect `vDSP_fft_zrip` works the same as `vDSP_fft_zip` with all imaginary part 0.0, but `vDSP_fft_zrip` does not work as expected. It seems `vDSP_fft_zrip` and `fft.rfft` uses different method for Optimizing for Real, so it's hard to get exactly the same result.

Comment: Interestingly, it looks like fft.rfft only keeps the first half plus one values for log two. So for 4 it keeps the first 3, for 8 it keeps the first 5, for 16 the first 9, etc., because the subsequent numbers sort of cancel out. Here is a note from scipy "When the DFT is computed for purely real input, the output is Hermitian-symmetric, i.e. the negative frequency terms are just the complex conjugates of the corresponding positive-frequency terms, and the negative-frequency terms are therefore redundant."

Comment: Yes. `vDSP_fft_zrip` does similar cut off to its result. But they are a little different. Maybe some scaling and rearrangements needed, but I cannot say something precise as for now. Some fft experts may know how to use `vDSP_fft_zrip` properly. It should be more efficient when given all reals.

Comment: @OOPer When the size of the input is a power of 2, I get the same in Python and your function, but when doing fftAnalyzer([1,2,3,4,1,2]) for example I get real=[13, -3, 1, -3, 1, -3] imag=[0,-1.73,1.73,1.11,-1.73,1.73] in python, but real=[10.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0, 1.0, 2.0] imag=[0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0] using your function

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of confusion around the difference between vDSP_fft_zip and vDSP_fft_zrip. The most immediate impact in your case is that the zrip output is packed, and needs to be scaled by 1/2 to equal the normal math output of a standard FFT.

This is buried somewhat in the Apple documentation: rather than appearing on the page for [vDSP_fft_zrip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/1579997-vdsp_fft_zrip), it's in the [vDSP Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html). However, it's still not clear from the guide how the input data is prepared in each case - and OOPer's answer is a big help with this.

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate

var input: [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]

let length = input.count
let log2n = log2(Float(length))
let fftSetup = vDSP_create_fftsetup(vDSP_Length(log2n), FFTRadix(kFFTRadix2))!

print("--vDSP_fft_zip---")
var real = input
var imag = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: length)
var splitComplexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(realp: &real, imagp: &imag)

vDSP_fft_zip(fftSetup, &splitComplexBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(log2n), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

print("real: \(real)")
print("imag: \(imag)")
print("-----------------")
print("DC      : real[0]")
print("Nyquist : real[2]")
print()
print()

print("--vDSP_fft_zrip--")
// only need half as many elements because output will be packed
let halfLength = length/2
real = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: halfLength)
imag = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: halfLength)

// input is alternated across the real and imaginary arrays of the DSPSplitComplex structure
splitComplexBuffer = DSPSplitComplex(fromInputArray: input, realParts: &real, imaginaryParts: &imag)

// even though there are 2 real and 2 imaginary output elements, we still need to ask the fft to process 4 input samples
vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &splitComplexBuffer, 1, vDSP_Length(log2n), FFTDirection(FFT_FORWARD))

// zrip results are 2x the standard FFT and need to be scaled
var scaleFactor = Float(1.0/2.0)
vDSP_vsmul(splitComplexBuffer.realp, 1, &scaleFactor, splitComplexBuffer.realp, 1, vDSP_Length(halfLength))
vDSP_vsmul(splitComplexBuffer.imagp, 1, &scaleFactor, splitComplexBuffer.imagp, 1, vDSP_Length(halfLength))

print("real: \(real)")
print("imag: \(imag)")
print("-----------------")
print("DC      : real[0]")
print("Nyquist : imag[0]")

vDSP_destroy_fftsetup(fftSetup)
```

printed:

```
--vDSP_fft_zip---
real: [10.0, -2.0, -2.0, -2.0]
imag: [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, -2.0]
-----------------
DC      : real[0]
Nyquist : real[2]


--vDSP_fft_zrip--
real: [10.0, -2.0]
imag: [-2.0, 2.0]
-----------------
DC      : real[0]
Nyquist : imag[0]
```

#### vDSP_fft_zip

**Input** is placed in the real array of the DSPSplitComplex structure and the imaginary array is zeroed out.

**Output** is complex and requires double the memory of the input. However, much of this output is symmetrical - which is how the packed output of zrip is able to represent the same information in half the memory.

#### vDSP_fft_zrip

**Input** is spread across DSPSplitComplex with DSPSplitComplex.init(fromInputArray: ) or by using vDSP_ctoz.

The fromInputArray: method does the same thing as ctoz, but it's an easier/safer approach - don't have to use UnsafeRawPointer and bindMemory.

**Output** is packed complex. When packed, output requires the same amount of memory as the input.

**Scaling:** results are 2x relative to standard Math FFT and need to be scaled as such.

---

see:
[vDSP Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html)

- Data Packing for Real FFTs
- Scaling Fourier Transforms

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you please update it to include how can we inverse the process as well (FFT_INVERSE)? I've been searching the internet for the past three days without any luck.

Comment: Thanks @Ibrahim! Glad this was useful for you. Consider submitting your inverse query as a new question and tag me if you can - or reply back here w a link to the new question.

Comment: Thank you @lentil for your kindness! I've finally finished preparing and posting my question. I've decided to ask about `iSTFT` in Swift. `FFT_INVERSE` is now part of the question. If you have experience in `iSTFT` in Swift, consider checking it out. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66847092/how-to-complete-istft-in-swift