# vDSP.FFT Swift enum vs. vDSP_fft_zrip

Tags: ios, swift, fft, accelerate-framework, vdsp

Apple has provided a [Swift `vDSP` enum](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp-snv) for more intuitively doing operations.

With this you can convert less readable code like

```
vDSP_vmul(arrayA, 1, arrayB, 1, arrayC, 1, vDSP_length(arrayA.count))
```

to

```
let arrayC = vDSP.multiply(arrayA, arrayB)
```

However, the nested [FFT class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/fft) seems to only support complex --> complex FFTs. In order to do a real --> complex FFT, taking advantage of conjugate complex symmetry, it seems you still need to use [vDSP_fft_zrip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450150-vdsp_fft_zrip) which [is not very intuitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531883/6528990) (classic old Apple docs issues).

Am I missing some way of doing a real --> complex FFT using the Swift enum? Thanks in advance!

Here's some example code using it:

```
let fft = vDSP.FFT(log2n: vDSP_Length(log2n),
                          radix: .radix2,
                          ofType: DSPSplitComplex.self)

/// create DSPSplitComplex, splitComplex, with array for real component,
/// zero array for imaginary component

fft?.forward(input: splitComplex, output: &splitComplex)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`vDSP.DiscreteFourierTransform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/discretefouriertransform). It supports complex-complex and complex-real. Accelerate's DFT will use FFT where it can. It also supports interleaved and split-complex data